# Foreach through elements retain the last value of the element

Tags: php, html

I would like to get the value of what I have echoed in the value of an HTML element but I used a foreach so it retains only the last value of the last loop. I would update the reqStatus depending on its ID through a post method to pass the variables.

HTML w/ foreach:

```
<form method = "POST" action="">
  <table>
    <th> Request ID:</th>
    <th> Request Status:</th>
    <?php 
      $requests = new OrderRequests();
      $requests->getAllOrders();             
      foreach($requests->orderList as $oList){?>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <input type="hidden" name="reqId" value="<?php echo $oList["request_id"];?>"><?php echo $oList["request_id"];?>
          </td>
          <td>
               <input type="hidden" name ="reqStatus" value="<?php echo $oList["request_status"];?> "><?php echo $oList["request_status"];?>
          </td>
          <?php if($oList["request_status"]=="Delivered"){?>
          <input type="hidden" id="reqIDUpdate" name="reqIDUpdate" value ="<?php echo $oList["request_id"];?>">
          <td>
              <input type="submit" class="button" value="Confirm Delivery">
          </td>
       <?php }}?>
       </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

After POST:

```
if (!empty($_POST["reqIDUpdate"])){
    $requestIDUpdate = $_POST["reqIDUpdate"];
    global $connection;
    $sql = "UPDATE order_request SET request_status = 'Received Delivery' 
    WHERE request_id = {$requestIDUpdate} ";
    mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    unset($_POST["reqIDUpdate"]);
}
```

Comment: *foreach so it retains only the last value of the last loop*. You echo the values. They should all be visible. Not sure I understand the question. Have you made sure the array contains what you think it should?

Comment: your issue is that you have `n` number of `name="reqIDUpdate"`, and as they are all in the same form, the last overwrites all previous values. You have a few options, some include - having each row in its own form; use javascript to disable all other inputs, except for the adjacent/sibling of the button clicked;

Answer (score 0):

Though you are echoing unique values, the value that gets assigned to the form hidden fields (reqId and reqStatus) are getting overwritten by new values in the foreach loop. By the end of the foreach loop, only the last values are saved in these hidden fields.